# xcode get UITabBar height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My app has a tabBarController as main controller and I need to get the height of tabBar from any view controller in order to calculate proper position for the rest of elements. How to get it programmatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I strongly suggest setting up your view hierarchy such that outer views are autosized by the container view and then more specific inner views can check the bounds of the outer layout view and lay themselves out appropriately at the appropriate times.

However, if your requirement makes that impossible (or extremely complicated and you really do need to specify points for everything), you can get the height of the tab bar with `UIViewController`'s `tabBarController` property:

```
// from inside the view controller
CGSize tabBarSize = [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] bounds].size;
```

Comment: One case where I think knowing the tabBar height is helpful, even when the views are autosized as you suggest, is when a view must be adjusted to account for the appearance of the keyboard. In this case, the keyboard will overlap the tabBar as well as part of the affected view, so that view must adjust itself by the difference between the keyboard height and the tabBar height. I'm thinking of a situation where the tabBar is the rootViewController and the active view is a descendant of that.

Comment: I have this exact same use case. Is there a better way to adjust the insets/height/origin for elements when using a tabBar for when the keyboard shows?

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift** use this:

```
let tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds.size.height ?? 0
```

It returns tabBar height when tabBarController is not nil, otherwise 0.